# is_dir() with non-english characters

Tags: php, directory, non-english

In php, is_dir() function omits directories which contains non-english characters. ie. is_dir("C:\ekşi") is not directory according to the function but it is. Is there any solutions to this case? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is no bug. Until PHP 6, no unicode caharcter support for this kind of operations.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#96140

Comment: I'm using PHP v.5.3.8 and I have no problems with unicode characters. Is there any specific function other than `is_dir` that these multibyte characters are (said to be) problematic?