# Delete dir with non english characters in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, encode, dir, non-english

I have a function that is scanning dirs on server, read files, do something with it , and then deletes the dirs (nested)

The function is quite long , So I will post the relevant part .

```
//many other things ...

    $dir_to_delete[] = $filename['dirname']; // the array to hold all the dirs.

        } // end for each

                $dir_to_delete_clean = array_unique($dir_to_delete); //clean array - we might have duplicated dir names 

                 foreach ($dir_to_delete_clean as $delete) {
                 o99_deleteDirectory($delete) ;
                 }
                // rmdir( $filename['dirname'] );

    return $attc_id;
    }
```

this is the delete function for non-empty dirs:

```
function o99_deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir)) return true;
    if (!is_dir($dir)) return unlink($dir);
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;
        if (!o99_deleteDirectory($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item)) return false;
    }
    return rmdir($dir);
}
```

It works great .

the problems is - when I checked for NON english characters ( German, Chinese, Hebrew, Arab, Cyrillic - or any other) - the script fails and stops...

I then tried rename() , rmdir() etc. - they all fail.
Is this a PHP bug ? 
How can I resolve the problem ? I can not even rename them to later delete 8because rename() fails as well...

Any Ideas ??

**Edit I**

I forgot to mention that it is for wordpress plugin - but I would assume that it makes no difference...

**Edit II**

I am posting here some languages if someone wants to try but do not have the right keyboard / language settings . I am not sure that cutting and pasting will give the right encoding, but can always try ...

- עברית (hebrew)
- 中國的 (chinese traditional)
- عربي (arabic)
- кириллица (cyrillic)
- ελληνικά (greek)
- öäüìíáàóò´Ä´` (German-Italian-Spanish and other european)

Comment: Is this the issue you're having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904004/is-dir-with-non-english-characters

Comment: hi, thanks - probably yes, but what would be the solution ? I tries to change encoding (mb_convert () htmlentities() ) and it fails all the same ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set locale before scanning or removing directories. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

I have not tried this but you can give it a shot. It might help.

Comment: thanks for comment - the locale is already set (by wordpress) - I did not mentioned above that it is a wordpress plugin, but I would assume it makes little difference. Trying to set it again on the script gave me no other result..